# What does the "muhsti" command mean or do?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apache-2.4

My server monitoring chart is showing a persistently high CPU usage.

It an ubuntu 64 bit server with LAMP setup.

Running htop reveals the following

[image]

The command muhsti is showing >99% CPU usage and is apparently run by www-data user.

The problem is that i have no idea what this command is, so i'm kind of reluctant to just terminate it without knowing its relevance.

A cursory google search hasn't provided any relevant info.

Anyone familiar with what this is?

Comment: It's not a real command, to my knowledge.  This looks like [cryptominer malware](https://www.google.com/amp/s/xorl.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/the-tiny-xml-mooner-linux-cryptominer-malware/amp/).  Your system has almost certainly been compromised.  See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/153161)

Comment: You were indeed right! The attack vector was a wordpress plugin muhstikx86. I was just practicing using wordpress. I have since deleted it, killed the processes and wiped the cronjobs it created to perpetuate itself. CPU usage is not under 10%. Thanks for the heads up. Cheers.

Comment: *"deleted it ... wiped the cron jobs..."* Next, destroy the server.  At the admitted risk of souding overly dramatic, think of a compromised machine as a house that may or may not have had one or more fixtures or pieces of furniture coated with a colorless, odorless, tasteless toxin that kills the victim swiftly but only after a potentially lengthy but highly random period of undetectable exposure.  Maybe you cleaned it all, maybe you didn't.  It is nearly impossible to be certain.